# What happens if a Python object is unbound?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import queue, threading

def getFromQueue(myQueue):
    while True:
        print(myQueue.get())

def putInQueue(myQueue):
    while True:
        putString=... #code that provides values
        myQueue.put(putString)


for msg in msgList:
    myQueue=queue.Queue()
    threading.Thread( target=getFromQueue, args=(myQueue, ) ).start()
    threading.Thread( target=putInQueue, args=(myQueue, ) ).start()
```

My goal is to have each pair of (getFromQueue and putInQueue) threads in a loop to share one unique queue.  When I reassign myQueue to a new Queue Object, what happens to the old Queue object?  Does each thread still use the original queue object that was passed when I spawned the thread or do all the existing threads get updated to point the new/latest one and all share a single Queue Object?

Comment: You're passing a reference of the queue object to use to your (threaded) functions. This reference does not change when you reassign the name `myQueue` in another scope.

Comment: since myQueue is getting reassigned, the old Queue object is no longer bound to a variable name. Does the queue object that the threads are referencing then get destroyed?

Comment: "since myQueue is getting reassigned, the old Queue object is no longer bound to a variable name" <- The name `myQueue` is bound to the old queue object in your threaded `while True` loops.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of `Queue` gets two more references to it before the global `myQueue` is assigned a new value: the `myQueue` parameter to `getFromQueue` and the `myQueue` parameter to `putInQueue`. An object is only destroyed once the *last* reference to an object is unbound.

The only effect on the previous instance of `Queue` as the result of the new assignment `myQueue = queue.Queue()` is that its reference count will decrease from 3 to 2.

Once *both* threads executing the functions for a given instance of `Queue` have exited, then that instance can be collected. The first thread that exits will result in the reference count decreasing from 2 to 1 when the local `myQueue` goes out of scope; the second will result in the reference count decreasing from 1 to 0.

Comment: I don't think where would be any confusion if the argument of the two functions was named differently, let's say `someQueue`.